# Referencia de objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Runat="Server" ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Me pidieron que no le ponga `runat="server"` al `textArea1`. Entonces en la parte del código no me aparece la etiqueta. Intente atrapar la etiqueta con el `master.findcontrol()` pero me tira un `NullException` (Referencia de objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto) y por lo tanto no me pasa los datos al `textArea2`

> ### <%: Title %>.
>
> #### Your application description page.
>
> Use this area to provide additional information.
>
> ```
> <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="10"  ></textarea>
>
> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Pasar A" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
>
> <textarea id="TextArea2" cols="20" rows="10" runat="server"></textarea>
>  </asp:Content>
> ```

code Behind

```
public partial class About : Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Master.FindControl("TextArea1").ToString()))
        {
           TextArea2.InnerText = Master.FindControl("TextArea1").ToString();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Si te fijas en el texarea con id "TextArea1" no tiene runat="server" así que tal vez por eso te sale el error

Comment: Si no le pones runat server entonces el servidor no se entera que ese control existe, y de ahi el error.

Comment: es que ese el tema! me pidieron que no le ponga el runat= "Server". osea dicen que es imposible atrapar la id del textArea1 de otra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quitas el runat="server" del control no vas a poder acceder a este desde el codigo backend

Si podras acceder al valor si usas la coleccion `Request.Form[]` pero no al control directo porque dejara de ser un Html Control

```
var valor = Request.Form["TextArea1"];
```

Comment: Hice la prueba pero no me funciono no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.   `Request.Form["TextArea1"] null string`

Comment: deberias revisar si ese input esta dentro del form, usa la developer tools del browser para ver que datos envia al servidor cuando se realzia el submit

Comment: Entonces me estas diciendo que no le voy a poder pasar datos? ya lo hice me lo toma sin ningun error, pero no me pasa lo que escribo en el textArea1 al TextArea2. Hago el Degub y tampoco me muestra que se estan pasando datos

Comment: asignar datos como si se tratara de un control asp.net me temo que no, si podras en el response enviar lo que quieres visualizar y asigna usando <%=this.Propiedad%> la propiedad la defines como publica en el webform